# how to change hour part in localdb

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle10g

How to change *hour* part in localdb timestamp column 4 hour back.

I have a table JOB_MONITOR

```
JOBID  JOB_TYPE         JOB_STATS   START_DATE
3      BIN Management   SUCCESSFUL  3/15/2018 5:50:29.269000 PM
```

I want to set START_DATE value to be 4 hr back like 3/15/2018 1:50:29.269000 PM

My server is in St. louis so when i do it with sysdate`-4/24. it update column value with respect to st louis time zone something like 3/15/2018 4:42:26.426000 AM..which i don't want. Hope now question is clear to everyone..

I want to set START_DATE value to be 4 hr back irrespective of time zone. just subtract 4 hr. I need this condition to test data locally.

Comment: always provide sample data

Comment: Do you mean you want to update the data in your `jobmonitor` table? Or just transform the data in a query? Or something else?

Comment: `start_date - interval '4' hour`

Answer (score 0):

Nor really clear what you are asking but I assume you are looking for this:

```
update jobmonitor set starttime = starttime - 4/24;
```

Answer (score 0):

User local keyword with systimestamp to get the local date:

```
SQL> column server_date format a20
SQL> column local_time format a20
SQL> column local_time_4hrs_back format a20
SQL> SELECT SYSDATE server_date, cast(SYSTIMESTAMP AT LOCAL AS DATE) local_time, CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AT LOCAL AS DATE) - 4/24 AS local_time_4hrs_back FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
SERVER_DATE          LOCAL_TIME           LOCAL_TIME_4HRS_BACK
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
3/16/2018 5:08:59    3/16/2018 14:38:59   3/16/2018 10:38:59
```